# Why do dishonour fees exist?

Tags: banking, history

In the event of a transaction not going through due to insufficient funds a dishonour fee is charged.
Presumably the cost of not making a transaction is lower than making a transaction, yet the cost of making a transaction is typically lower than an attempted transaction that fails. (All of the banks I've used have had no transaction fees, yet they've had high dishonour fees in the event an auto-payment fails). This seems backwards to me.

Comment: Is that because you don't have enough funds in your account or because you have entered the payee's details incorrectly?

Comment: This is in the situation of not having enough funds in the account, I haven't run into this situation in a while, I'm just curious as to what the rationale is for the fees.

Comment: So your trying to make a payment with not enough funds in your account, so the bank will have to do more work in checking if your account has enough funds and then reversing or stopping the transaction going through. These type of fees should be in the Financial Service Guide for the account you have and you should have received a copy when you opened the account. So you try to make a payment with money you don't have and expect not to be penalised for it!

Comment: It isn't cheaper -- it's in addition to the successful transaction still required. More importantly, it messes up planned cashflow and is a behavior the bank actively wants to discourage -- so the fee is high as a penalty and deterrent. If you don't like paying it, don't do that and everyone will be happier.

Comment: I would have presumed that validation that you have enough money account would be done in all transactions, not just those that fail, because it's something that must be checked in order for the transaction to be successful. Reversing the transaction shouldn't be necessary since I'd presume the validation would be performed prior to the transaction taking place. How would a failed transaction adversely affect a bank's operations?

Comment: Why are you not checking your own account to see if you have money available before you make a payment, and the fees are specified in the documentation when you open your account. How about taking some responsibility regarding your own finances instead of blaming others.

Comment: Like I said earlier, this question isn't about anything I'm facing at the moment, but rather is an "out of curiosity" question.

Comment: Read the fine print, it is in there so they can do it if you don't comply. If I had a shop and a customer came in to buy things, but then did't have the money to pay for these things, I would like to also charge him for wasting my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the United States, many banks aim to receive $ 100 per year per account in fees and interest markup.  There are several ways that they can do this on a checking account.  These examples assume that there is a 3 % difference between low-interest-rate deposit accounts and low-interest rate loans.

- The customer carries an average balance of $ 8,000.  The bank pays 0.25% interest.  (3%/year / 2 = 1.5%/year; 1.5%/year - 0.25%/year = 1.25%/year; $ 8,000 * 1.25%/year = $ 100/year)
- The bank charges an $ 8 monthly fee.  ($ 8/month * 12 months/year = $ 96/year)
- The customer gets a "rewards" debit card that pays the customer $ 2 per $ 1,000 the customer charges on the debit card.  The bank charges the merchant an extra $ 1 per $ 100 the customer charges.  If the customer charges $ 1,000 of transactions per month on the debit card, the bank gets $ 96 per year of markup.  ($ 1,000 / month * (1% - 0.2%) = $ 8 / month * 12 months / year = $ 96 / year).
- The bank charges the customer $ 2 every time they use an ATM.  If the customer uses an ATM once per week, that is $ 104 per year.
- The bank charges the customer $ 40 per overdraft.  3 overdrafts / year = $ 120 / year.

Or some combination of these markups that adds up to $ 100 / year.  For example:  A two dollar monthly fee = $ 24 / year, plus a $ 2,000 average balance at 0.05% = $ 29 / year, plus $ 250 / month in rewards debit card usage = $ 24 / year, plus $ 2 / month in ATM fees = $ 24 / year.

Before it was taken over by Chase Manhattan in 2008, Washington Mutual had a business strategy of offering "free" checking with no monthly fees, no annual fees, and no charges (by Washington Mutual) for using ATMs.  The catch was that the overdraft fees were **not** free.  If the customers averaged 3 overdraft fees per year at $ 34 each, Washington Mutual reached its markup target for the accounts.

Comment: I understand banks want to maximise their profit, but I'm curious as to why dishonour fees are so popular, most of the accounts I've used have them. Is it something the bank is trying to discourage, or is it just that customers are willing to accept the fee?

Comment: @HamishFarrant, if you didn't try to spend money you didn't have, then you would not have to worry about these fees.